# How to use jade mixins on client side

Tags: pug

We can compile jade template as an anonymous function and call it when we need to render it on client side. What about mixins?

mixin:

```
    mixin tiny(text)
      button.tiny #{text}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use them like this:

Declare your mixin somewhere, then use `+` to call it when you want and pass the parameters in.

```
mixin person(name) // Declare
  li.name= name

ul 
  +person('cat') // User
  +person('dog')
  +person('pig')
```

In your example

```
 mixin tiny(text) // Declare
      button.tiny= text

 +tiny('text') // Use
```

Comment: How would one do this if the mixin is in a separate file?