# How to compile jade mixin to javascript to be used in client

Tags: express, pug

I have some mixins needed by both server and client(dynamic rendering). I'm using Express, Grunt, if that's of any interest.

Just for example, see the following mixin:

```
mixin book(data)
  .header data.title
  .description data.description
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) says we could pre-compile jade template to javascript. But `jade --client --no-debug book.jade` just gives the following output:

```
function template(locals) {
  var buf = [];
  var jade_mixins = {};
  var jade_interp;

  ;return buf.join("");
}
```

It's quite confused. I'v found that some others met the same problem, but no solution or even futher explanation is given.

- [how to using jade Mixin in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068728/how-to-using-jade-mixin-in-javascript)
- [How to use jade mixins on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958302/how-to-use-jade-mixins-on-client-side)
- [Compile mixin to JS in JADE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040717/compile-mixin-to-js-in-jade)

So, is it really possible to share mixins between server and client? If possible, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seemed to work:

**mixins/userItem.jade**

```
mixin userItem(user)
    .user= user.name

+userItem(user)
```

That way your template gets compiled correctly using `jade --client --no-debug mixins/userItem.jade`.

This will work like expected. `template({ user: { name: 'foo' })` returns `<div class='user'>foo</div>`

AND you can also use your mixin in you server-side rendering:

**users.jade**

```
include ./mixins/userItem

extends layout

block content
    each user in users
        +userItem(user)
```

**server.js**

```
render('users', { users: [{ name: 'foo' }] });
```

Comment: what if we get the `users` by AJAX?